# How to clear Text in search box once the user selects other option

Tags: search

I have created a view for to search my channels. But when user searches for a specific channel, and when he clicks any other option or on any other event,he redirects to other page but text in search box is not cleared,what i want is, the text in search box should get cleared once he clicks on other option.How can i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the value of search box with Javascript when page get ready. Create a simple custom module and create a js file in that module. Something like:

```
//custom.js
(function($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('SEARCH-FROM-INPUT').val('');
  });
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Attach this file to the pages those have that search form.

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'SERCH_FORM_ID') {
    $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/custom.js' => array(
        'type' => 'file',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:** updated code as per @Andy comment, adding js with '#attached' property

Comment: You should use [`#attached`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) in this situation to add the JS to the form.

Comment: Also that JS won't necessarily play nicely with other modules (for example if you did anything AJAXy, the search query would suddenly disappear). You should write attach handlers such that they can be called multiple times (and you can't know when) without causing problems. Typically [`.once()`](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#jquery-once) is used for this.

Comment: How to add JS to the form? Can you please edit the code?

Comment: @Tejaswini: I updated the code. You could do it yourself. Have a look at `#attached` form property. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#attached

Comment: That how can i know. That is your views specific. Here `SEARCH-FORM-INPUT` is the jquery selector for your form's input field. And `SEARCH_FORM_ID` is your views exposed from id. Views exposed form id are in form of `views-exposed-form-VIEWS-MACHINE-NAME-VIEWS-DISPLAY-NAME`, Normally views machine name and views display name have `underscore(_)` in their name, remove those `underscore(_)` with `hyphen(-)`. Or use `dpm($form_id)` on first line in `hook_form_alter()` it will print the `form_id` of your exposed form.

Comment: I got SEARCH-FORM-INPUT for search form and module is working fine now.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in 2 ways:

1. You can use **javascript** to clear the value of textfield after
   page load or on click.
2. You need to rewrite field or rebuild form when option changes.

It`s all that i can say without some code.